# Souce map for several source files in coffee-script.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

when I trying to use more than one .coffee file

```
<script data-src="js/file1.coffee"      type="text/coffeescript"></script>
<script data-src="js/file2.coffee"      type="text/coffeescript" ></script>

<script src="lib/coffee-script.js"></script>
```

The content of the 1st script is:

```
console.log 'file1'
```

The content of the 2st script is:

```
console.log 'file1'
```

I get the source map for the 1st file only. And all runtime errors and output in the chrome console refer to an unexisting last string `file1.coffee`

And the console output is:

```
file1        file1.coffee:1 
file2        file1.coffee:1
```

Comment: Sometimes the coffeescript compiler concats all the .coffee files creating a new file, then it generates a .js file with a source file pointing to that concatenated file.